# Inheriting metadata between publications, map and topics in Tridion Docs

Tags: taxonomy, metadata, tridion-docs

I was wondering if there is a nice approach for inheriting metadata fields between different levels of authoring in Tridion Docs (i.e. publications, maps and topics). In other words, can anyone suggest a mechanism for inheriting metadata fields, so that, for instance, a metadata field that is set on a publication automatically gets applied to all topics within that publication.

I imagine something like this could be done with event system code, or similar. However, I feel like it could get pretty messy in terms of handling versions, conflicts, etc. I'm thinking a better approach may be to handle this type of logic on the presentation side - meaning, we have a web application that queries for publications and the application can contain some logic to assume all topics within a publication are tagged with the same metadata fields as the publication.

Answer (score 1):

It seems one decent approach would be to use templates for this purpose. The issue that we are trying to solve is the ability to create mass amounts of Docs topics without needing to select the same subset of metadata tags to apply each and every time we add a new topic. So what we can do is build a template that already has these metadata fields applied and use that template to create a set of new topics, so that they all will have the necessary fields applied automatically, by just using this new template.